# Are these mushrooms safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, mushrooms

I was chopping up some portabella mushrooms (purchased at Costco) for a stir fry and noticed that the flesh of some of the mushrooms turned a dark brown (left):  [image: Bad mushrooms?]

It has a slightly rougher texture, and smells stronger than the whiter mushrooms. Never seen a mushroom like this before, is it safe to eat?

Comment: Did you buy the mushrooms from a (reputable) seller or did you pick them yourself?

Comment: @bob1 I bought them from Costco

Comment: Also, all the mushrooms in the image are from the same package.

Comment: Thanks - that makes it easier, it means they are actually edible mushrooms, something that is not always guaranteed for mushroom problems on here.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaricus_bisporus --  nothing unusual, the white ones are immature. Nothing wrong those unless mishandled like any other mushrooms.

Comment: @bob1 Or, at least, it means that if he eats them and gets mushroom poisoning, he can sue CostCo for selling him poisonous mushrooms.

Comment: @DanMašek I was talking about the one on the _left_ with the dark colored flesh. It doesn't look like any other portabella that I handled before. All the pictures that I look at show white flesh, like the one on the _right_.

Comment: Well... Are these okay to eat?

Comment: @AndroidWonKenobi are they slimy and / or smell fishy or sour?

Comment: They smell stronger/woodier than the other mushrooms, and they feel rough.

Comment: Looks like oxidation, perhaps some mushroom pests like maggots or slugs ate into the cap and caused the interior to oxidate?